# Error: No "exports" main defined in graphql-upload/package.json

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs, express-graphql

Have installed graphql-upload, do

`import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload';`

And getting this error:
Error: No "exports" main defined in graphql-upload/package.json

Dependencies:

```
"graphql-upload": "^14.0.0",
"graphql": "15.8.0",
"graphql-request": "^4.2.0",
"graphql-tools": "^8.2.0",
"@nestjs/axios": "^0.0.7",
"@nestjs/common": "^8.4.1",
"@nestjs/config": "^1.1.5",
"@nestjs/core": "^8.4.1",
"@nestjs/graphql": "^9.1.2",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
```

The version of node: v16.10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was in the .default build settings.
You can remove it, but when we removed it we saw the problem with other modules, so we resolved this issue via this:

```
import Upload = require('graphql-upload/Upload.js');
```

It looks very dirty, but it works.

You can check conversation about this module in issues on GitHub: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/issues/305#issuecomment-1136574019

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this problem.
Apparently, the the new version `i.e. ^16` ,has a major [update](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/releases/tag/v16.0.0)

now you need to do

`const Upload = require('graphql-upload/Upload.mjs');`

or

`import { default as Upload } from 'graphql-upload/Upload.mjs';`

Instead of `.js`, all the imports needs to be from `.mjs`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

`graphql-upload` library doesn't have any main `index.js` re-export for all of its functions. It has direct file exports for all the specific functionalities. It is specified in its `package.json` file under `exports` key like so:

```
"exports": {
    "./GraphQLUpload.js": "./GraphQLUpload.js",
    "./graphqlUploadExpress.js": "./graphqlUploadExpress.js",
    "./graphqlUploadKoa.js": "./graphqlUploadKoa.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    "./processRequest.js": "./processRequest.js",
    "./Upload.js": "./Upload.js"
  },
```

So instead of directly importing from package root you need to specify a sub-module path like this:

`import graphqlUploadKoa from "graphql-upload/graphqlUploadKoa.js";`

Reference: [`package.json` of `graphql-upload`](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: Then use
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
and see an error:
TypeError: (0 , graphqlUploadExpress_js_1.default) is not a function
    at Function.main (/blablabla/src/main.ts:28:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: For me by doing this `import graphqlUploadExpress from 'graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.js'`,  type of  `graphqlUploadExpress ` returned a function. Make sure you write that `.js` extension in the import line also.

Answer (score 4):

I have personally put a ts-ignore for ignore errors.

```
// @ts-ignore
import GraphQLUpload from 'graphql-upload/GraphQLUpload.js';
// @ts-ignore
import Upload from 'graphql-upload/Upload.js';
```

And imports like that. I hope it can help even if it's dirty!

Answer (score 2):

The owner of the package just chooses to restrict importing everything from the index file, so to run the new version (> 13.0.0) you have to change the way you are importing the package:

```
const graphqlUploadExpress = require('graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.js');
```

or

```
const GraphQLUpload = require('graphql-upload/GraphQLUpload.js');
```

Alternatively, you can download grade your package to version 13.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Just like every answer, the maintainer of the package has chosen to restrict the imports for this package. I run into the same issue and have decided to stick with version 13 moving forward.

You can use the old imports with version 13

```
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload';
```

Answer (score 1):

use version v15.0.1 for graphql-upload

import like this:

import GraphQLUpload from 'graphql-upload/GraphQLUpload.js';

import graphqlUploadExpress from 'graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.js';

https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/issues/314#issuecomment-1140441744

https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/releases/tag/v15.0.1

Supported runtime environments:

Node.js versions ^14.17.0 || ^16.0.0 || >= 18.0.0.

- Projects must configure TypeScript to use types from the ECMAScript modules that have a // @ts-check comment:
- compilerOptions.allowJs should be true.
- compilerOptions.maxNodeModuleJsDepth should be reasonably large, e.g. 10.
- compilerOptions.module should be "node16" or "nodenext".

https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-upload

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I fixed it using an alternate package [graphql-upload-minimal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-upload-minimal)

Here is the old code

```
const {
  graphqlUploadExpress, // A Koa implementation is also exported.
} = require("graphql-upload");
const { GraphQLUpload } = require("graphql-upload");
```

Here is the new code

```
const {
  graphqlUploadExpress, // A Koa implementation is also exported.
} = require("graphql-upload-minimal");
const { GraphQLUpload } = require("graphql-upload-minimal");
```

This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I fixed using version 15.0.2 (only that version works for me)

> package.json

```
{
   "dependencies": {
      "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.1.7",
      "@nestjs/axios": "1.0.0",
      "@nestjs/common": "^9.3.9",
      "@nestjs/config": "^2.0.0",
      "@nestjs/core": "^9.3.9",
      "@nestjs/graphql": "10.2.0",
      "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.3.9",
      "graphql": "^16.6.0",
      "graphql-upload": "15.0.2"
   },
   "exports": {
     "./GraphQLUpload.js": "./GraphQLUpload.js",
     "./graphqlUploadExpress.js": "./graphqlUploadExpress.js",
     "./graphqlUploadKoa.js": "./graphqlUploadKoa.js",
     "./package.json": "./package.json",
     "./processRequest.js": "./processRequest.js",
     "./Upload.js": "./Upload.js"
   }
}
```

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 10
  }
}
```

> **/resolver.js

```
    // @ts-ignore
    import Upload = require('graphql-upload/Upload.js');
    // @ts-ignore
    import GraphQLUpload = require('graphql-upload/GraphQLUpload.js');
    
    ...
    
    @Mutation(() => Boolean, {
       name: 'uploadImages',
       description: 'Insert array photos',
    })
    async uploadImages(
        @Args('files', { type: () => [GraphQLUpload] })
        files: [Upload],
        @Args('metadata')
        metadata: UploadImagesMetadataArgs,
      ): Promise<Boolean> {
        const functionPrefix = 'uploadImages';
        try {
          let uploadImagesArgs: Array<UploadImagesArgs> = [];
          for (const file of files) {
            // @ts-ignore
            const { filename, mimetype, encoding, createReadStream } = await file;
const stream = createReadStream();
            const chunks = [];
            for await (const chunk of stream) {
               chunks.push(chunk);
            }
            const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            uploadImagesArgs.push({ buffer, filename, mimetype });
            // your code with connect with services for save your images
            return true;
          }
        } catch(error){
             // your code 
             return false;
        }
      }
```